# How to get Zabbix to report out of date packages?

Tags: yum, zabbix, amazon-linux

How do I configure Zabbix to report for Linux servers that have out of date packages?

The following shell command reports if package updates are available:

```
/usr/bin/yum --debuglevel 2 --security check-update 2>/dev/null \
    | grep -P '(?<! 0 packages) available$'
```

If no updates is returns an empty string.
If updates are available returns:

```
10 packages available
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a user parameter with content similar to the following:

```
UserParameter=yum.updates,/usr/bin/yum --debuglevel 2 --security check-update 2>/dev/null | grep -P '(?<! 0 packages) available$'
```

Place this line either into the main configuration file for Zabbix agent (zabbix_agentd.conf) or into a separate file (which might be better if you are planning on distributing this user parameter on a lot of servers) and include it or its directory using `Include` directive.

In the current form, you have a user parameter than returns a string, so in Zabbix frontend you would configure an item with key `yum.updates` and type of "Character". A trigger would then be:

```
{host:yum.updates.strlen()}#0
```

However, the problem with string items is that they cannot be graphed. It would be nice to have an item that returns an integer with the number of updates available, like so (note the trailing part):

```
UserParameter=yum.updates,/usr/bin/yum --debuglevel 2 --security check-update 2>/dev/null | grep -P '...' || echo 0
```

You will also have to change the regular expression in the `grep` so that it returns only an integer.

The benefit of this approach is that the number of available updates can be graphed and you can also set a higher threshold for the trigger:

```
{host:yum.updates.last()}>10
```

See also [official documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/config/items/userparameters) on user parameters for full details.

Comment: Update count comes from:
    `/usr/bin/yum --debuglevel 2 --security check-update 2>/dev/null | egrep '(.i386|.x86_64|.noarch|.src)' | wc -l`

Comment: @Greg: Is there anything more I can help you with?

Comment: After changing the agent config file and restarting Zabbix my Zabbix server reports that the agent is done. Nothing obvious in the /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log log file.

Comment: Had to change the timeout in zabbix_agentd.conf to 10 seconds

Answer (score 1):

I have a Zabbix Template for this purpose, both for yum and apt package managers. I'll leave it here in case someone finds it useful. Instructions in repo README:

yum version (RHEL, CentOS...) -> https://github.com/AkuLink1/zabbix-template-yum-update-monitoring

apt version (Debian, Ubuntu...) -> https://github.com/AkuLink1/zabbix-template-apt-upgrade-monitoring